# Azure Cloud Services and Git continuous deployment?

Tags: git, azure, continuous-deployment, azure-cloud-services

Is there a way by which I can use Git not only as a code repository but also for a build and continuous deployment to Azure (Cloud service, NOT web site)? I suspect not given the missing build environment unless but want to confirm this before writing it off.

In theory I can see having Git hosted on a Windows server that also does the build and deployment - not sure if anyone has reduced this to practice.

Comment: This [github project](https://github.com/tjanczuk/git-azure) looks promising. I just googled "githooks azure deployment".

Answer (score 3):

Update : This is now possible

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/#step6

Working like charm with both git and tfs.

Comment: Partially, since it works only if you pay for and use visual studio online and it's specific GIT servers. We already have our GIT repositories - we just want to deploy from there onto the cloud services.

Comment: FWIW, I just set up my private Git server with a githook that pushes to TFS, which builds and pushes to Azure. I have to pay TFS only for build minutes, so we'll see how it goes. I'm mostly satisfied with the whole setup.

Comment: @Illuminati can you please share some details on how you got this to work with Git on VSO? I have a Git repo on VSO which is linked to my cloud service but pushing a new version to the 'master' branch does nothing (i.e. I can't see any new deployments). Documentation only talks about 'checking in' with TFS.. Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is support in the new management portal for directly publishing "Web Sites" from Git, but not for Cloud Services as you have already noticed.  However, there is support for doing that with TFS.  There is currently a free [TFS hosted preview](http://aka.ms/tfspreview) available, and I have a blog post that walks through configuring [Continuous Integration with Azure Web Sites and TFS Preview](http://aka.ms/tfsazwsvsci). The process is nearly identical for a Cloud Service.

Comment: Thank. However I'm running into this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087025/tfspreview-com-and-azure-certificates-not-playing-well-at-deployment)

Comment: -1 Failing to see how "he process is nearly identical for a Cloud Service." is justified